# How to create a Service Principal Name (SPN) for an AWS RDS-managed SQL Server instance computer object in AD?

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services, sql-server, amazon-rds, spn

We are using [**AWS RDS for SQL Server**](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver/), an *AWS managed service*. We joined our RDS to our self-managed AD:

[image: AD]

We found the Active Directory Service Principal Name (SPN) for the RDS-managed-service database instance in the logs, and  published that and used it for accessing the database.

However, the SPN changed after a couple of weeks. AWS recreated the instance.

We need an SPN that will not change, so someone thought we should try adding our own SPN and hope that will not change if the RDS instance is re-created. I haven't been able to find any information about static SPNs and RDS. I found [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/register-a-service-principal-name-for-kerberos-connections?view=sql-server-ver16) to use the command:

> setspn -S MSSQLSvc/myhost.redmond.microsoft.com:instancename redmondaccountname

However, this requires access to the OS, which I don't have since I'm using a normal RDS for SQL Server (not the custom one). Does anyone have any related experience?

**Notes:**

- I need a static SPN for PowerBI.
- I'm not using an EC2 instance or RDS for SQL Server Custom *(not allowed by my client)*. I don't have access to Windows Server or any tool inside. I cannot change anything in the OS. Any command must be run from the SQL Server Management Studio or a similar software.

Comment: `However, this will involve having access to the OS` not necessarily. An SPN is an attribute on an object in Active Directory. Setspn is only one way of adding it updating the attribute.

Comment: SQL self-registers the SPN each time it starts up. (It appears that AWS RDS SQL does not differ in this regard.) Can you tell us what it was, before and after you noticed a change? That might help us find an answer. And I agree with Greg -- even if you do end up needing to do it manually, you don't need to run the `setspn` command from the machine that SQL is running on. You can run it from any machine in your AD.

Comment: You don't need setspn at all. There are plenty of tools that provide the capability to edit attributes. AD Users and Computers is one.

Comment: Hi @GregAskew, do you know any command that I can run in the SSMS? At RDS for SQL Server, I don't have access to anything else. I cannot connect via Remote Desktop or anything else. I don't have access to the OS since all is managed by AWS.

Comment: Hi @DougDeden, I guess that RDS for SQL Server installed some patches. Every week, our RDS is restarted to install some AWS stuff.

Comment: `know any command that I can run in the SSMS?` no. SSMS is not used to modify attributes in Active Directory. AD Users and Computers or ADSIEdit. You should know this due to this is a site for sysadmins.

Comment: `I don't have access to Windows Server or any tool inside. I cannot change anything in the OS` then you need to speak to the people who can. It should take two minutes to do this, you are spinning your wheels and wasting time.

Comment: So basically you: created something, it was "re-created" with a different name, this broke access to the application, and now you want to create a name that is deterministic and will not change. That's reasonable, and is a lot different than "I must enter magic command in SSMS". You still need to speak with the system administrators at the company, because they need to add the SPN for you. You should also be aware that using Power BI in this way is notoriously flaky and problematic and a support nightmare.

Comment: Can you tell us what the SPN was, before and after you noticed a change? That might help us find an answer.